# A question about the solution of $x^2+4x-32 \lt 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was given the following problem

$$ x^2+4x-32 \lt 0 $$

and I came up with the following solution $x \lt -8 , x \gt -4$ and then I, unsucessfully, put it in interval notation $(-\infty, -8)\cup (4,\infty)$. The correct answer is $(-8,4)$. I'm having trouble understanding why it's this interval and not the other. I graphed the equation but still couldn't come to a conclusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As $x^2+4x-32=(x+8)(x-4),$

we have $\{x-(-8)\}(x-4)<0$

If $x-4>0\iff x>4$ we need $x+8<0\iff x<-8$ which is impossible

If $x-4<0\iff x<4$ we need $x+8>0\iff x>-8\implies -8<x<4$

More generally, if $(x-a)(x-b)<0$ where $a,b$ we shall have $a<x<b$

Comment: @gekkostate, what if $(x+8)(x-4)>0?$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way to see it is: draw the parabola $\;x^2+4x-32=(x+8)(x-4)\;$ . This is an upwards parabola (since the main coefficient is positive) and it intersects the $\,x-$axis at $\;(-8,0)\;,\;(4,0)\;$ , so drawing it is **very** easy (no need to be exact).

Well, now: where is that parabola *under* the $\;x-$axis? This is the geometric equivalent to ask the algebraic question: for what value we have $\;x^2+4x-32<0\;$ ?

Clearly the parabola is under the abscissa axis when $\;-8<x<4\;$...and voila!

The above is the method taught to kids in high school here.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you graph it, you see a parabola concave up, with roots -8 and 4, and it is below the x axis between the roots.